# How to use linq to exclude Specific HtmlAgility ChildNodes

Tags: .net, linq, html-agility-pack

I am trying to parse all children of a HTMLNode where the child is not a hidden input in vb.net using HtmlAgility.

Using the following code:

```
    If node.InnerHtml.Length > 10000 Then
                'Parse the current node's child nodes
                For Each child As HtmlNode In node.ChildNodes _
                                                  .Where(Function(c) c.NodeType <> HtmlNodeType.Text _
                                                             AndAlso c.NodeType <> HtmlNodeType.Comment _
                                                             AndAlso c.Name <> "script" _
                                                             AndAlso c.GetAttributeValue("type", "no").ToString() IsNot "hidden")
                    RecursiveHtmlParse(child)
                Next
End If
```

Unfortunately the hidden input child nodes are still being parsed. I've tried for hours and just can't get the foreach to skip them.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`Is`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kb136x1y.aspx) and [`IsNot`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3bat82c.aspx) operators in VB.NET check for reference equality. Two strings which contain the same value may actually reference different objects in memory.

Try this instead:

```
AndAlso c.GetAttributeValue("type", "no") <> "hidden"
```

Or this

```
AndAlso Not c.GetAttributeValue("type", "no").Equals("hidden")
```

Comment: I used AndAlso c.GetAttributeValue("type", "no") <> "hidden" and it worked like a charm thanks. This will definitely be learning experience for me in the future.